# Convert adjacency matrix to vector

Tags: python, numpy, adjacency-matrix

I would like to convert an adjacency matrix to a vector. I already came up with a solution that works but seems to be overly complex (using a workaround with pandas). There must be a more easy way to do this?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = np.array([[0,1,2,3],
              [1,0,1,0],
              [2,1,0,0],
              [3,0,0,0]],
             dtype=float)

il = np.tril_indices(len(A))
A[il] = np.nan
A_df = pd.DataFrame(A)
A_stacked = A_df.stack().reset_index()
A_vector = A_stacked[0]
```

which gives you:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    1.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Does `np.triu_indices(len(A),k=1)` and `A[iu]` does the job for you? `k` is the offset from the diagonal.

Comment: FYI: Take a look at [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:
Use diagonal offset argument `k` of [`np.triu_indices()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = np.array([[0,1,2,3],
              [1,0,1,0],
              [2,1,0,0],
              [3,0,0,0]],
             dtype=float)

iu = np.triu_indices(len(A),k=1)
A[iu]
```

Results in

```
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0])
```